# PrintStream unexpectedly moving to a new line?

Tags: java, output, println, printstream

I can't figure out why my code is causing the PrintStream to go to a new line:

```
// displays the total time of the leak in months from the calculateLeakTime() method. 
    String leakTime = LeakCalculator.calculateLeakTime(); 
    System.out.println("The total time of the leak is " + leakTime + " months.");
```

The output looks like this:

"The total time of the leak is 12
months."

I can't figure out why months is being printed on a new line.  I even tried this:

```
// displays the total time of the leak in months from the calculateLeakTime() method. 
    String leakTime = LeakCalculator.calculateLeakTime(); 
    System.out.print("The total time of the leak is " + leakTime);
    System.out.println(" months.");
```

And I got the same output.  Can someone explain why it's moving "months" to a new line?

Thanks,

Kevin

EDIT:  Here's the calculatLeakTime() method:

```
static String calculateLeakTime() throws ParseException{

    long leakEndMili = getLeakEnd(); 
    long leakBeginMili = getLeakBegin(); 

    long timeDays = ((leakEndMili - leakBeginMili) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    double timeMonths = (double) (timeDays * 0.0328549); 

    System.out.println(timeMonths);

    String monthsRounded = String.format("%.0f%n", timeMonths); 

    return monthsRounded; 
    }
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show us the method `calculateLeakTime`. It is very likely that the method is causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "%n" from the following line:

> String monthsRounded = String.format("%.0f%n", timeMonths);

Answer (score 0):

It's doing this because your `LeakCalculator.calculateLeakTime()` method adds a line feed, `"\n"` to the end of the String that it returns. To tell for sure, print out the individual chars that make up the String returned.

To solve this, fix your `LeakCalculator.calculateLeakTime()` method so that it doesn't add a line-feed to its returned String. Perhaps it should return a number and not a String.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> I suspect this is the issue format("%.0f%n", timeMonths)

Well yes, `%n` is a new-line character.

Comment: Thanks...  I suspect this is the issue

`format("%.0f%n", timeMonths)`

Comment: Thanks a lot...  Once you pointed out it was something in my method, it made sense.